# Initramfs unpacking failed: no cpio magic booting 20.04.3

Tags: boot

I was trying to fix an [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361516/browsers-and-other-windows-crashing-20-04-3-lts) and after rebooting I got stuck on the following screen.

```
Initramfs unpacking failed: no cpio magic
Failed to execute /init (error -2)
Kernel panic ~ not syncing - No working init found. Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance.
Hardware name: Dell Inc. Precision M4800/0T3YTY, BIOS A16 12/01/2015
Call Trace:
dump_stack0+0x6d/0x8b
? rest_init+0x30/0xb0
panic+0x101/0x2e3
? do_execve+0x25/0x30
? rest_init+0xb0/oxb0
kernel_init+0x100/0x110
ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
Kernel Offset: 0x2bc0000 from oxfffffff8100000 (relocation range: 0xfffffff000000-oxfffffffff)
---[ end Kernel panic ~ not syncing: No working init found. Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance 1---
```

Comment: What exactly did you do?

Comment: Help getting past whatever error is preventing me from booting. I didn't do a whole lot, I selected different drivers.